# elpa certificate could not be verified

Tags: package-repositories, ubuntu

When I run `package-list-packages`, I'm getting an error:

> The TLS connection to elpa.gnu.org:443 is insecure for the following reason:
>
> certificate could not be verified

I found a few other reports of this, but all seemed to be due to some local mis-configuration ([like this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37805/m-x-list-package-fails-with-error-certificate-could-not-be-verified)). I ruled this out by recompiling the latest version of Emacs from the emacs-26 branch, and launching with `emacs -Q` (that's Emacs 26.0.91). The problem still persists.

Another clue: this only happens on my desktop running Ubuntu 14.04, not on my laptop running Debian testing. So I suspect it may be due to something important being outdated on the ancient version of Ubuntu I'm saddled with (and cannot update, it's a work computer).

How can I resolve this, or at least find the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible ways that Emacs/TLS can be misconfigured but it seems likely this is simply a duplicate of the question you linked, especially given your distribution's GnuTLS version matching the version I am testing with. [My answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38404/3985) is likely to be the cause.

Comment: I'm guessing one or more of the issues in your linked answer were responsible; whatever it was, the problem is now resolved without my having changed anything in my local configuration.

Comment: The certificate was fixed, so that should have got it I’d think.